# MSSCCI compliant Mercurial client

Tags: mercurial, labview

Hi I am looking into a Microsoft Source Code Control Interface (MSSCCI) compliant Mercurial Client for integrating Mercurial into my IDE ([LabVIEW](http://www.ni.com/labview)). I thought [HgSCC](http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html) was getting close since it claims it uses the MSSCC interface for it's integration with Visual Studio, however it doesn't turn op in LabVIEW as an option.

Does anybody know a MSSCCI compliant client or can verify that HgSCC is indeed such a client and LabVIEW is just lazy in recognizing this one?
I looked at the registry key used by LabVIEW `HKEY_LocalMachine\SOFTWARE\SourceCodeControlProvider\InstalledSCCProviders` which only lists PushOK's SVNSCC client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version of HgScc was MSSCCI compliant.

You can get it here (http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html), scroll at the **very bottom** to the news dated "24 may 2008". There you can find a download link. Also, that version was tested only with MSVS 2005/2008, so it may not work with LabVIEW.

The recent versions of HgSccPackage supports only MS SCC Package API (MSVS only), which is not MSSCCI compliant.

Comment: Thanks, this one at least shows up. I have however some issues with configuring, so I wait a little bit before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/)?