# Mercurial and SQL Server Management Studio GUI plugins?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, ssms

Does no such plugin exist?

So to be clear, I realize that RedGate has their own SSMS SCC app, and I realize that VSS2k5 will integrate in. I'm looking to stay with Hg as that's where my source already is, and I'ld like to find something that my team can stay consistent with on their tools.

As is, I guess I'm going to have to just run it through TortoiseHg and a folder with manual maintenance. Which isn't terrible, but naturally it would be nicer if there was an app pre-existing that I could consume.

And no, I don't have the time or inclination to write one myself. Not before Summer 2011.

Thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two versions of HgScc plugin:

1. HgScc - uses old MS SCCI API, works with MS VS2005/2008/2010 and with some third party IDEs. Last version of this plugin was released in 2008. It is not actively developed anymore, because MS SCCI API is very limiting and does not allow a tight integration with Visual Studio.
2. HgSccPackage - uses MS SCC Package, works only with MS VS2008/2010. This version of plugin currently in active development.

To get the first version of HgScc follow the instructions here:
[MSSCCI compliant Mercurial client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330548/msscci-compliant-mercurial-client)

Comment: I presume you're the same zz-sergant as what runs that project, so can I ask a couple questions? Will they conflict with each other for starters? Do I need to uninstall the one?

Comment: Yes, it is me.

You can have both plugins installed at the same time, they do not conflict with each other.

Comment: Um, let me make sure I was clear (sorry, slow morning) ... can I have both hgscc(MSSCCI) and hgsccpackage(MS SCC) installed together?

Comment: Last time I checked (a year ago) they works fine together. But I just checked right now and unfortunately they are conflicting :(

So, you can have installed only one of the plugins, either HgScc or HgSccPackage.

If you have installed both, and seen the error after switching a provider in Visual Studio options, then you may need to run:

devenv.exe /resetskippkgs

to make it possible to load the package again.

Comment: I actually managed to stop what I was working on and installed it and just got everything restarted and it looks like it works quite well together. Perhaps order of install is important? Thanks again!!

Comment: Well, the problem is that both plugins uses the assembly with name HgSccHelper.dll. And if one of the plugin allready loaded in process (made active in visual studio), then the error occurs when you switch to another HgScc plugin. I think if you use HgSccPackage in MSVS, and HgScc in third party IDE, than they should works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Red Gate SQL Source Control is looking into supporting Mercurial in a future version, http://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/39019-sql-source-control/suggestions/803713-mercurial-support-as-source-control-system.

Comment: thanks for that information. I have a coworker evaluating the "standalone" SQL SSMS SCM right now, but I personally would prefer Hg, since that's where all our code lives, might as well be able to pull db build scripts from there too. Thanks for the heads up, I'll make sure to watch them.

Comment: The full release of SQL Source Control 2.1 is now available, http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=13147.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2012 (Denali) is using the Visual Studio 2010 Shell as the basis for the new Management Studio. I haven't tried it yet but I am hoping that tools such as VisualHg will work in Sql Server 2012. I will update this post after I get on my laptop that has the 2012 SQL Management Studio installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [hgscc](http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html)? I know it integrates with Visual Studio, but I haven't tried it with SSM

Comment: I had SSMS and VS installed on my system before I installed hgsccpackage on my system, and it neither registered itself nor offered to for SSMS. It's one of my installed options in VS tho. (I personally prefer VisualHg but I don't mind hgsccpackage at all)