# Mercurial MSSCCAPI Provider?

Tags: mercurial, powerbuilder

Does anyone know of an MSSCCAPI provider for Mercurial? I'd like to try out Kiln/Mercurial with PowerBuilder, but the PowerBuilder IDE only recognizes MSSCCAPI providers (which is *not* the same as MS SCC Package API) and the only one I can find is the [original version of HgSccPackage](http://www.newsupaplex.pp.ru/hgscc_news_eng.html).

I've contacted the developer and he has stated that he will not switch back from the Package to the regular API so that option leaves me with no upgrade path. This question was asked in [July of 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3330548/103701) with only the response that I have already mentioned. I'm hoping there's been something new since then. Thanks!

Comment: +1: Although the MSSCCI API apparently has some fundamental [problems](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/scm_ide_integration.html) it is still used by applications such as [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-up-source-control-microsoft-windows.html#f7-37366).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to post this as a comment to the question.

Maybe your PowerBuilder source control methodology is holding you back. Do you control the PB objects inside of the PBLs? Or do you control *.sr? (PB Export) files, maybe using PowerGen to synchronize them into the PBLs?

At work, a set of PBLs is published to programmers by the Build Manager at every build. This avoids having to pay one PowerGen license per programmer for them to sync up (which can take 5-40 minutes depending on the number of changes and the app size). You need just one license for the build server.

One caveat is that programmers need to understand the flow correctly so not to lose code or cause regressions, but a good inspection of the TortoiseHg diff window should allow to catch most problems before committing.

Comment: The PowerBuilder source control methodology is definitely the issue. Unfortunately, I have no control over that. I'm not sure what you mean by "Do you control the PB objects inside of the PBLs?" But it doesn't really matter, since I have found a work-around. I can use PB's native SCC as a starting point. That creates *.sr* exports of each object. I can then use Mercurial to version those exports. By throwing a couple of Cli commands into custom toolbar buttons, it's not too kludgy to work with.